# Does Commander Tax reset?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander

Example:

- I cast my commander from my command zone, paying no tax.
- Commander dies
- Goes to command zone
- Summon from command zone, paying tax (2)
- I bounce my Commander to my hand, play him from hand
- He dies a second time.

The next time I play him from the command zone is his tax (2) or (4)?

Comment: Note that to be accurate; you should avoid using the term "dies" here; because a commander that is sent to your command zone instead of your graveyard will not count as dying - things that say "whenever a creature dies" will not trigger, for example.

Comment: Strictly speaking, a commander **can** die. Moving it to the command zone instead of the graveyard is a choice the player needs to make. It is just commonly treated like the default behavior because it is almost always the right choice.

Comment: @murgatroid99 true it can die, but the process CefG is describing doesn't fit the game's technical definition of dying, since they are using the replacement effect choice.

Comment: It is entirely possible for a commander to die, and later go to the command zone, and then be played from the command zone.

Comment: I think it was clear enough from the question as originally worded that the user was talking about using the Commander rule to send the commander to the command zone instead of the graveyard. And I don't think my comment would be likely misread as saying that a Commander can never die.

Answer (score 6):

The commander tax never resets, but it also doesn't count times when it isn't cast from the command zone; so you must pay an additional {4} in your case.

> 903.8. A player may cast a commander they own from the command zone. **A commander cast from the command zone costs an additional {2} for each previous time the player casting it has cast it from the command zone that game**. This additional cost is informally known as the “commander tax.”

The additional 2 per time it has been cast counts every time it is cast from the command zone.